# wsdl2java error: "Fail to create wsdl definition" while generating java code

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, cxf

I'm trying to generate java service code with apache-cxf `wsdl2java` tool for wsdl:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mpromonet/spring-onvif/master/src/main/resources/wsdl/remotediscovery.wsdl

> MBA-Anton:bin asmirnov$ ./wsdl2java
>   "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mpromonet/spring-onvif/master/src/main/resources/wsdl/remotediscovery.wsdl"
>   25.11.2014 16:16:49 org.apache.cxf.configuration.jsse.SSLUtils getDefaultKeyStoreManagers WARNING: Default key managers cannot be
>   initialized: /Users/asmirnov/.keystore (No such file or directory)
>   [Fatal Error] addressing:2:2: The markup in the document following the
>   root element must be well-formed.
>
> WSDLToJava Error: org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLRuntimeException: Fail to
>   create wsdl definition
>   https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mpromonet/spring-onvif/master/src/main/resources/wsdl/remotediscovery.wsdl:
>   WSDLException (at /wsdl:definitions/wsdl:types/xs:schema/xs:schema):
>   faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: Problem parsing
>   'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing'.:
>   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The markup in the document following
>   the root element must be well-formed.

Why is it trying to create wsdl definition instead of generating java code? How can i fix it?

Verbose log:

> MBA-Anton:bin asmirnov$ ./wsdl2java -V
>   "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mpromonet/spring-onvif/master/src/main/resources/wsdl/remotediscovery.wsdl"
>   Loading FrontEnd jaxws ... Loading DataBinding jaxb ... wsdl2java -V
>   https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mpromonet/spring-onvif/master/src/main/resources/wsdl/remotediscovery.wsdl
>   wsdl2java - Apache CXF 2.7.13
>
> 25.11.2014 16:18:39 org.apache.cxf.configuration.jsse.SSLUtils getDefaultKeyStoreManagers WARNING: Default key managers cannot be
>   initialized: /Users/asmirnov/.keystore (No such file or directory)
>   [Fatal Error] addressing:2:2: The markup in the document following the
>   root element must be well-formed.
>
> WSDLToJava Error: org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLRuntimeException: Fail to
>   create wsdl definition
>   https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mpromonet/spring-onvif/master/src/main/resources/wsdl/remotediscovery.wsdl:
>   WSDLException (at /wsdl:definitions/wsdl:types/xs:schema/xs:schema):
>   faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: Problem parsing
>   'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing'.:
>   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The markup in the document following
>   the root element must be well-formed.
>
> org.apache.cxf.tools.common.ToolException:
>   org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLRuntimeException: Fail to create wsdl
>   definition
>   https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mpromonet/spring-onvif/master/src/main/resources/wsdl/remotediscovery.wsdl:
>   WSDLException (at /wsdl:definitions/wsdl:types/xs:schema/xs:schema):
>   faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: Problem parsing
>   'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing'.:
>   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The markup in the document following
>   the root element must be well-formed.     at
>   org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.execute(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:420)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.tools.common.toolspec.ToolRunner.runTool(ToolRunner.java:103)
>     at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.run(WSDLToJava.java:113)
>     at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.run(WSDLToJava.java:86)   at
>   org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.main(WSDLToJava.java:184)
>   Caused by: org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLRuntimeException: Fail to create
>   wsdl definition
>   https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mpromonet/spring-onvif/master/src/main/resources/wsdl/remotediscovery.wsdl:
>   WSDLException (at /wsdl:definitions/wsdl:types/xs:schema/xs:schema):
>   faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: Problem parsing
>   'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing'.:
>   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The markup in the document following
>   the root element must be well-formed.     at
>   org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLDefinitionBuilder.parseWSDL(WSDLDefinitionBuilder.java:97)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLDefinitionBuilder.build(WSDLDefinitionBuilder.java:69)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.frontend.jaxws.wsdl11.JAXWSDefinitionBuilder.build(JAXWSDefinitionBuilder.java:83)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.frontend.jaxws.wsdl11.JAXWSDefinitionBuilder.build(JAXWSDefinitionBuilder.java:60)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.processWsdl(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:198)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.execute(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:164)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.execute(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:412)
>     ... 4 more Caused by: javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException (at
>   /wsdl:definitions/wsdl:types/xs:schema/xs:schema):
>   faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: Problem parsing
>   'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing'.:
>   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The markup in the document following
>   the root element must be well-formed.     at
>   com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.getDocument(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2198)
>     at
>   com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.parseSchema(WSDLReaderImpl.java:830)
>     at
>   com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.parseSchema(WSDLReaderImpl.java:864)
>     at
>   com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.parseSchema(WSDLReaderImpl.java:654)
>     at
>   com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.parseTypes(WSDLReaderImpl.java:610)
>     at
>   com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.parseDefinitions(WSDLReaderImpl.java:320)
>     at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2352)
>     at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2338)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.loadDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:261)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.getDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLDefinitionBuilder.parseWSDL(WSDLDefinitionBuilder.java:78)
>     ... 10 more Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The markup in
>   the document following the root element must be well-formed.  at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:247)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:287)
>     at
>   com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.getDocument(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2188)
>     ... 20 more

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that this has to do with the following import in [ws-discovery.xsd](http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/04/discovery/ws-discovery.xsd):

```
<xs:import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" schemaLocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing"/>
```

To my surprise, the link http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing works but it redirects (HTTP 301) to http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/ first (mind the trailing `/`).

I think `wsdl2java` does not follow the redirect. You could monitor/sniff network connections to find out exactly.

Anyway, how to solve it.

You can use a [catalog file](https://jaxb.java.net/guide/Fixing_broken_references_in_schema.html) with wsdl2java:

- http://cxf.apache.org/docs/wsdl-to-java.html

Make a local copy of the remote schema and use a catalog file like this one:

```
SYSTEM "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" "src/main/resources/addressing.xsd"
```

(`addressing.xsd` is your local copy).

Comment: after `./wsdl2java -catalog ./wsdl/catalog -d ./generated -server ~/Documents/dev/src/spring-onvif/src/main/resources/wsdl/remotediscovery.wsdl` i have generated folder with files. the only problem i have is: `WSDL document file:/Users/asmirnov/Documents/dev/src/spring-onvif/src/main/resources/wsdl/remotediscovery.wsdl does not define any services` i thought it defines one service to response to discovery signals

Comment: @4ntoine This is a different question, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

It's SSL issue when you access the wsdl file. You can download the wsdl file first, and then do generate the java codes by using wsdl2java.

Comment: no, that's not the reason. i've tried to download the file and run with local file path

Answer (score 0):

Remove the stylesheet entry `<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="http://www.onvif.org/onvif/ver20/util/onvif-wsdl-viewer.xsl"?>` from wsdl and try regenerating again.

Comment: did not help, still the same error message unfortunately

Comment: You said that you have downloaded wsdl file and ran from your local. Have you also downloaded ws-discovery.xsd and referred properly in wsdl file?